# how to get google profile information inside domain from web app? google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth

One simple question, but for a very long time I cannot find an answer to it. I want to create a simple html-form in which the data of the user who opens this form should automatically be loaded (name, phone, position, photo). Ideally, i want to filter tables and other data by its name.
No matter what the form is, I need a method that I can use to get the data. All users are inside the domain.

f.e. i can do "**Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();**" to get users email. But how to get phone number? oAuth can not give me full information, which i can find in contacts (or am i wrong?).

Thank you and sorry for my english.

Comment: How is the web app executed? As yourself or as the user accessing the web app?

Answer (score 1):

If you are an admin for the domain, you can use the [Admin Directory API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory).

Comment: thanks. exactly! for the last few years I have been global, but in the new organization I have no rights yet. *childy*